# how to install mobicents on tomcat

Tags: sip

Hi I am trying to install mobicents, I have installed Tomcat7 and Maven2 and the plugins for eclipse and all these are working fine however I am stuck trying to load mobicents onto Tomcat. I found this tutorial on mobicents site http://www.mobicents.org/installation-tomcat.html
but am a little unclear on what I am supposed to do. I set up a folder called  CATALINA_HOME inside my .apache-tomcat-7.0.41,  copied unzipped files from
"mss-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-apache-tomcat-7.0.50-1403120216.zip" downloaded from 
"https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/" 
and ran ./bin/catalina.sh as I am using debian host. This however achieves nothing and no files are copied. There are a lot of post on forum about mobicents so I was wondering if someone could explain the install instruction as the ones found on mobicents link above are a little unclear to a noob like myself, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to rebuild Mobicents SIP Servlets yourself ?
Just use https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/ and follow the steps in User Guide at http://docs.telestax.com/sip-servlets-getting-started-with-mss-for-tomcat-7/

Comment: thanks that link solved my problems and gave me new ones :) moving forward.

Comment: lol, at least this is moving forward. Feel free to upvote the answer so that others know it has been helpful.

Comment: The links that you provided are returning just a 404. Do you have updated links?

Comment: Yes, we have been hosting the documentation on a real website after a couple of DoS attacks on Cloudbees recently. See http://docs.telestax.com/sip-servlets-homepage/ and http://docs.telestax.com/sip-servlets-getting-started-with-mss-for-tomcat-7/

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to run MSS/Tomcat 7 in Eclipse?

Comment: There is none at the moment, but if you want to contribute one to the community that would be a great addition.